# Generating Dynamic Table Rows for HTML Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

Im having a Html Email Template for Invoice Like Bellow.

```html
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Item ID</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Qty</td>
   <td>Unit Price</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>{ItemID}</td>
   <td>{Name}</td>
   <td>{Qty}</td>
   <td>{UnitPrice}</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have an Item List with 5 Items,

```html
List<ItemList> ItemList = new List<ItemList>();
```

The class Structure for Item List

```html
public Class ItemList{
 public int ItemID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int Qty {get;set;}
 public decimal UnitPrice {get;set}
}
```

My Question is how to dynamically generate the table rows for the tbody based on  the item list which i have by replacing the values with {ItemID},{Name},{Qty},{UnitPrice}?
Im using ASp.Net MVC4, I have came across a library called Html Agility Pack, please any body let me know how to archive this using Html Agility Pack.

Comment: `String.Replace` is usual answer to "how to replace something in string"... But I think you are looking for some other answer - to get one consider showing code you have now to render that and explain what you have problem with/want to improve. It is not even clear if you want to render it on page or in some sort of server side code (than why you have ASP.Net tag?)

Comment: Hi Alexei, I have to render this HTML sting, and send this Table as Email, Thanks.

Comment: Is that the *actual* HTML template? If it is, then you don't really need an HTML specific library like HAP. Since the markup is also valid XML, you can use .NET native XML API like `XDocument`...